# tikz class diagram recursive relation

Tags: tikz-pgf, metauml

i need to draw a classdiagram with recursive rectangled pointers. 
My intention was to draw two rectangles and rotate one as read in a other post...
but how do i position them right?

MWP

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % see geometry.pdf on how to lay out the page. There's lots.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
arrows,
shapes,
chains,
matrix,
positioning,
shapes.multipart,
calc,
scopes}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}


\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rectangle,draw,yscale=1.2,x=3,rotate=135,fill=black,name=1] {};
          \node[rectangle,draw,yscale=1.8,rotate=0,name=2] {};
          \umluniaggreg{1}{2}
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

this is what i get:
[image: what i get...]
and this i what i need:
[image: what i need...]
can somewone help me position them somehow and draw a line on the edge of the diamont to the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

A pure TikZ solution. In it is for arrows used `arrows.meta` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, 12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{geometry} % see geometry.pdf on how to lay out the page. There's lots.
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
%                chains,
%                matrix,
%                positioning,
%                scopes,
%                shapes,
%                shapes.multipart
                }
%\usepackage{tikz-uml}
%\usepackage{ifthen}
%\usepackage{xstring}
%\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n1) [draw, minimum height=2em, align=center, fill=cyan] {Baustein\\[1em]};
\draw[-{Diamond[length=7mm]}] (n1.north) |- ++ (2,1) |- (n1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I this what you looking for?

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for!
can you give me a link to a description of this part: 
) |- ++ (2,1) |- (n1);
i wold like to understand the coordinates...

Comment: all is described in TikZ & PGF manual, chapter *2.15 Specifying Coordinates* (first tutorial, page 37) . roughly said: `+` means that line is moved for amount from last one, and `++` that new coordinate is relatively to previous one, `|-` means that first draw vertically than horizontally.